# jQuery quicksearch in dynamic tables

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am creating a table with id after making ajax call. I am retrieving rows of data from db and creating a dynamic table with id and displaying it. I want search feature too. I have used quicksearch but it doesn't search in dynamic tables i guess. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/). Is the best grid pluging I have seen in Jquery.